# Html or Css attributes make list's item displays first

Tags: html, list, css, html-lists

I'm using the `<ol>` and `<ul>` tags to make a list in HTML.
The results on web view like this:

> 1
>   2
>   3

I want to using HTML/CSS attribute to set the 2 item is the first displayed item like this:

> 2
>   1
>   3

I don't want to change order of `<li>` elements in HTML. I want to add an  attribute to `<li>2</li>`. Does HTML/CSS support this?

Comment: please show your code

Comment: I don't want to use JS because the simple of progamming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS flexible boxes allow you to reorder content.

Put the element you want to display first in the first group of ordered content, and all the other list items in the second.

```css
ol { display: flex; flex-direction: column; }
li { order: 2; }
li:nth-child(2) { order: 1; }
```

```html
<ol>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
    <li>d</li>
</ol>
```

I'll leave looking up the -vendor-prefix properties to support older browsers as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: I like the exercise bit, mainly because of IE. But for what OP is asking, seems ideal. ;P